# Using Webrequest/response

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

Can someone explain to me the "workings" of webrequest/response in this situation, i have this function:

```
 Public Shared Function DoRequests(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim sr As StreamReader = Nothing
    Try
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        sr = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Return sr.ReadToEnd()
    Catch
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        If sr IsNot Nothing Then sr.Dispose()
    End Try
End Function
```

Why .net 2.0 creates 5 threads to run the request with this usage?:

```
DoRequests("HTTPS LINK HERE")
```

The problem is as said above, .net creates 5 threads expecifically 3 here:

`Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)`

and 2 here:

`Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()`

The process is fast but the threads doesn't get cleaned.. at least not right away, i'm asking why.. or if there is somewhat a "better" way of doing it, since though i understand why 2 threads are created, i don't understand why 5 are needed for a simple request/response, and i still need to run it on a thread if i want to be sure the UI doesn't freeze...

I know Garbage collector exists but in this case i think this wouldn't be the case for letting him cleanup since it's the requests that creates it's thread

Comment: Define "better" way to do things. `WebRequest` works, and well. Are those threads causing you a performance problem? If not, then why worry about it? But if you're really curious, source code for `HttpWebRequest` is at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#f2ab2d685cb26f13. Have a good time.

Comment: Well, it's not really a performance problem, just 5 threads seems kinda excessive for a simple request.
Anyway thanks for the link ;)